# Can I get the model information for my hard drives with a command in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive

Is there a Linux command that would allow me to get model information for hard drives? I'm running CentOS.

I want to compare the hard drives on two VPS providers that I use.

Comment: "Compare" how? Speed? Reliability?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of these should work:

```
smartctl --all /dev/sda
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

However, if this is a VPS you may not get back reliable data.  If that's the case (you get back what's obviously a virtual HDD), there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Yes, it tells me that is a VMware disk: "Device: VMware   Virtual disk     Version: 1.0" Thanks.

Comment: Yep, no way to tell what's underneath that virtual disk...

Comment: Also `lshw` is good